# URL search path redirect with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, search, redirect, path

can you please help, I'm trying to redirect search results from one URL path to another. The original path is

http://www.dominio.com/?s=searchquery

And I want search results to show here:

http://www.dominio.com/search/searchquery

I have tried many 301 redirects but I don't get it to work, can you help?

Thanks!
Sandra

Comment: You can refer this article,you will get some idea.https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search/searchquery.html$ index.php?s=searchquery
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Uwe, just one more question, how can I change searchquery to be any term? Thank you!